# Pega 7.3. Error Missing Application. (Pega-API-CI-Branch)

Tags: jenkins, pega

I have a issus on Pega 7.3. I have to automate the check conflict on jenkins. For this, I use a http request authentification such as automate the PEGA-Unit. So I go to the PEGA-API, and use getconflict with returns a list of conflicts that would occur if that branch was merged. A url link is displayed (http://localhost:8081/prweb/api/v1/branches/{Id Branch}/conflicts), but when i use it, i'v got this error:

```
"pxObjClass": "Pega-API-CI-Branch",
"errors": [
{
  "ID": "Pega_API_029",
  "message": "Missing Application",
  "pxObjClass": "Pega-API-Error"
}
```

Here my request on jenkins

```
 httpRequest authentication: '0e1600f3-08d1-496d-9408-148448f76896', httpMode: 'GET', responseHandle: 'NONE',outputFile: 'conflict.xml', url: 'http://172.31.180.192:8081/prweb/api/v1/branches/TestA/conflicts'
```

I don't understand the error and I don't find the answer in the website of pega (But I have seen people who have the same problem as me). I don't know if it's clear or not but if someone can help, it'll be nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the values for `Param.ApplicationName` and `Param.ApplicationVersion` in `pySetApplicationDefaults` Data Transform in `Pega-API-CI-Branch`.

If you are also going to merge, you're also going to need to `update` `pySetVersionPasswordDefaults` assuming you have a locked ruleset or want to lock your ruleset. (You really need to keep your rulesets locked at all times when using branches.)

I'll look into why this isn't posted to the `PDN`.